# Unable to create superuser in cvat

Tags: docker, annotations

I am able to build and run cvat tool. But when I trying to create a superuser then it is giving me below error.

***ImportError: No module named 'gitdb.utils.compat'***

I am running below command for creating a superuser.

**docker exec -it cvat bash -ic 'python3 ~/manage.py createsuperuser'**

Does anyone have any idea or suggestion for the above problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the newer version of gitdb does not work with cvat (default version is 4.0.2), you can follow Furkan Kirac answer but with gitdb version is 0.6.4:

```
# pip uninstall gitdb
# pip install gitdb==0.6.4
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is most probably due to a newer gitdb2 python package.
If cvat is already built as a docker container, for testing, you must log into the container as root, uninstall it and install an older gitdb.

> docker exec -it -u root cvat bash
>
> pip3 uninstall gitdb2
>
> pip3 install gitdb

Then, running python script must work. If that is the case, then a persistent solution is to rebuild the containers.

You need to edit Dockerfile as below:

> # Install git application dependencies
>
> ...
>
> fi
>
> RUN pip3 uninstall -y gitdb2
>
> RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir gitdb

Run "docker-compose build".

Hope this helps.